# ! Missing number, treated as zero. and ! Extra \endcsname Errors using algorithm, algorithmic packages

Tags: latexmk

I have no idea what this error is complaining about or how to fix it. Here is minimum explainable problem:

```
\documentclass{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{footnpag}                   
\usepackage{algorithm} 
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{comment}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[!ht]
   \caption{caption}
   \label{alg:flipflop}
   \begin{algorithmic}[1]
      \Procedure{blah}{}
         \State blah
         \While{blah}
            \State blah
         \EndWhile
         \State blah
      \EndProcedure
   \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

returns the following string of three errors:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \c@float@type 
l.510 \end{algorithm}

The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \endcsname 
l.510 \end{algorithm}

A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Extra \endcsname.
<recently read> \endcsname 

l.510 \end{algorithm}

I'm ignoring this, since I wasn't doing a \csname.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your Minimal Working Example is minimal, yes, but it's not "working". Please complete it including the `\documentclass` and relevant `\usepackage`s and make sure that the error happens when you compile the example.

Comment: AIAA.cls is not in texlive do you have a link? (or better can you reproduce the problem with a standard class)

Comment: if AIAA.cls is based on revtex, then you can change the example to use `\documentclass{revtex4-2}` which gives a similar error

Answer (score 3):

The problem is caused by what looks like a bug in float.sty, in its definition of `\newfloat`.  This macro is used by the algorithm package to define the algorithm environment. The bug does not manifest itself if document class article is used, but does manifest itself when revtex4-2 is used.  This is because revtex4-2 modifies how floats are implemented.

Revtex4-2 does provide a bug fix, but it only takes effect after the beginning of the document.

One can work around the problem by putting the following lines in the source file before the `\usepackage{algorithm}` line:

```
\usepackage{float}
\makeatletter
\let\newfloat\newfloat@ltx
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 1):

Had exactly the same error. Commenting out `\usepackage{algpseudocode}` worked for me.